# Shrink Windows 10 partition for Ubuntu 16.04 Dual Boot

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, multi-boot, ubuntu-16.04

In some web pages I've read that before installing Ubuntu you should resize the Windows partition from within Windows (with diskmgmt.msc) but when I boot Ubuntu for instalation (Windows was installed before) there's an option where I can set the disk space for each OS, so my question is if it's necessary to resize the disk partition from Windows when I can do it while I'm installing Ubuntu?

P.D. Both OS will be installed in the same harddisk (Windows was the first OS to be installed)

Answer (score 1):

It's better to resize your partition from windows because windows will manage on it's own the process.

Doing so from Ubuntu may have create strange behaviors within windows, because some files may have moved without noticing windows.

Comment: BTW, before shrinking the partition, in Windows turn off Hibernate and reduce the size of the pagefile, because these files cannot be relocated safely. This will allow more free space for Ubuntu, if needed.

Comment: What's the point on turning off Hibernate and reducing pagefile size?

Comment: It'll remove the hiberfime.sys and pagefile.sys files that you can find on C: (disable "hide system protected files" in folders settings to actually see them). These files are really huge (16 GB ~ each).

Answer (score 0):

I would perform a system restore back to where I before put lots of things on the hard drive, or a factory reset to get rid of most immovable files to resize your partition. Before you do any of that, if you want your data back, you can back up and restore you data for later.